# core dumped and dynamic memory allocation in c

Tags: arrays, c, file, struct, dynamic-arrays

```
static int get_token(char *line, char fields[2][30], char *delim){
   char *token = strtok(line , delim);
   int flag = 0;
   while (token != NULL) {
        //printf("%s\n", token); 
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        if (flag == 0)
            strcpy(fields[flag], token);
        else if(flag == 1)
            strcpy(fields[flag], token);
   }
   return flag;
}

static void sort_data(){
   // printf("reading the file ...........");
   FILE *fileOpen = fopen( filename , "r");
   char line[LINE_SIZE];
   char fields [2][30];
   while(fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, fileOpen) != NULL){
         int no_of_token = get_token(line, fields, ",");
         printf("%d\n",no_of_token);
         if(no_of_token != 2){
               //printf(" number of fields is not 2 for entry %d",j);
               continue;
         }
   printf("%s \n %s",fields[0],fields[1]);
   }
}
```

In the above program what i want to do is to open a (.csv)file read it line by line and then pass those line to the get_token function so token can be genrated and i want only those line which have 2 fields
i also want to get values of those 2 tokens so that i can pass it in add_record function(which i have not written yet) and create a dynamic struct array so thati can sort it and store it in other file.
but i am not getting the values of the fields instead my output when i run it shows core dumped.
so please help me with this problem and also dynamic allocation of the struct as i am new to programming in c.And also sorry if my code hurt your eyes

Comment: First, your get_token function always returns 0.  You need to increment the flag variable inside your tokenizing loop if you want to return the number of tokens parsed.  It's difficult to know why the program is crashing without the test data, but it is likely that since "flag" never is incremented, a string is never copied into fields[1] and you try to printf uninitialized memory.  A suggestion would be to remove the final print to be sure that's the code causing the crash, and/or break the printf into separate pieces to see if it prints fields[0] but crashes printing fields[1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some mistakes in your code. I've fixed those. Just compare two code files and you'll be able to understand what is wrong with your code. Mostly, you've misplaced lines, couldn't write proper algo etc...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define LINE_SIZE 1024


int get_token(char *line, char fields[][30], char *delim) {
    int token_cnt = 0;

    char *token = strtok(line , delim);
    while(token != NULL) {
        // check if there is more than two tokens
        if(token_cnt >= 2) {
            return 3;
        }
        //printf("%s\n", token);
        strcpy(fields[token_cnt++], token);
        // update token
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    return token_cnt;
}


void sort_data() {
    static char line[LINE_SIZE];
    static char fields [2][30];

    char *input = "input.csv";

   // printf("reading the file ...........");
    FILE *fp = fopen(input, "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("error: can't open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        int no_of_token = get_token(line, fields, ",");
        
        printf("no_of_token: %d\n", no_of_token);

        if(no_of_token != 2) {
            // printf(" number of fields is not 2 for entry %d",j);
            printf("no_of_token is not 2...:(\n\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("first-elem: %s \nsecond-elem:%s\n",fields[0],fields[1]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

int main() {

    sort_data();

    return 0;
}
```

**input.csv:**

```
A,B
C,D
X,Y
P,Q,R
U,V
```

**output:**

```
no_of_token: 2
first-elem: A
second-elem:B

no_of_token: 2
first-elem: C
second-elem:D

no_of_token: 2
first-elem: X
second-elem:Y

no_of_token: 3
no_of_token is not 2...:(

no_of_token: 2
first-elem: U
second-elem:V
```

Note: you could also throw error if there's less than or more than 2 elements...its your choice